# error: unknown type name ‘mxArray’

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

When I try to use MATLAB mex command to compile a c file, I met the following error

> error: unknown type name ‘mxArray’

The error code is here

```
const char *model_to_matlab_structure(mxArray *plhs[], int num_of_feature, struct svm_model *model);
struct svm_model *matlab_matrix_to_model(const mxArray *matlab_struct, const char **error_message);
```

I don't understand why MATLAB doesn't recognize the mxArray type. How could I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you including the required header `#include "matrix.h"`

Comment: @slayton IMO, you should include `mex.h` instead of directly including `matrix.h`, since the former includes the latter and has prototypes for a number of functions that are useful in mex files.

Comment: @Praetorian yea you're right, that is a typo on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. It turns out that I forgot

```
#include "mex.h"
```